# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect, File.Copy

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to copy a file from network shared folder to another folder in the same network. It **threws the exception**.

Verified and the *file exists*.

```
Source: \\servername\folder1\Old\ABC_1382.pdf

Destination: \\servername\folder1\New\

File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destiFilePath, true);
```

The file size is 400Kb.

Comment: What exception is thrown? Does the destination folder exist?

Comment: You need to remove last ```\``` from destination path `\servername\folder1\New\`

Comment: `Destination` should be *file name*, e.g. `\servername\folder1\New\ABC_1382.pdf`

Comment: @towel That is the question title, Yes the folder exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Source` and `Destination` should be *file names*. If `destiFilePath` is in fact a *directory*, let's add *source* file name (`ABC_1382.pdf`)

```
  string sourceFilePath = @"\\servername\folder1\Old\ABC_1382.pdf";

  string destiFilePath = @"\\servername\folder1\New\";

  // Uncomment, if you are not sure that directory exists 
  // and you want to create it with all subdirs
  // Directory.CreateDirectory(destiFilePath);

  File.Copy(sourceFilePath,
            Directory.Exists(destiFilePath) 
              ? Path.Combine(destiFilePath, Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath))
              : destiFilePath,
            true);
```

Comment: How can i add the "@" when the path is a variable? is it just a concat? doing "@" + path didn't work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @iamCR: `@` is for *verbatim string*: I just don't want to *double* each "\", i.e. `@"\\servername\folder1\Old\ABC_1382.pdf" == "\\\\servername\\folder1\\Old\ABC_1382.pdf"`. If you use *variables* you *should not* use `"@"`, but `Path.Combine` when necessary, e.g. `sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(server, directory)`